# excel multiple column matches

Tags: vba, excel

I have following kind of data in excel:

```
Col 1       Col 2       Col 3
a           Apple       x & y & z
a           Ant         x & y & z
a           Aeroplane   x & y & z
b           Ball        m & n
b           Bat         m & n
c           Cat         k & l
c           Carrom      k & l
c           Can         k & l
```

I want to break/split values in column3 by & character and then create additional row for each value. something like below should be result:

```
Col 1       Col 2       Col 3
a           Apple       x
a           Apple       y
a           Apple       z
a           Ant         x
a           Ant         y
a           Ant         z
a           Aeroplane   x
a           Aeroplane   y
a           Aeroplane   z
b           Ball        m
b           Ball        n
```

values I used are just samples actual data contains words seperated by & in column 3

[adding image since formating getting messed up for table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDxHk.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: sorry havent put any efforts. all i tried was various excel formulas like to break the value but none worked. new to vba so posting here.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a "we do your work" service. If want to get some real results out of your VBA activities - there are no detours. You better pick up a good book/tutorial and start learning. Or you decide to hire somebody and pay for the work. Chances are small that anybody will do it for free.

Comment: not expecting you to work or solve it. any pointers on how it can be done should be sufficient.

Comment: Is this a once only operation to get the data in the format you want or will there be new data arriving in the first format you need to change into the second format?

Comment: Well, then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: @Rob this is just once only operation. Is there any excel formula that I could use to spilit value and copy entire row? if not should I try some vba to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do what you are intending with the information given. I encourage you to look up the methods used as they are quite fundamental and novice in difficulty. I have put down comments that explain what each section is doing. GL

```
Sub test()
Dim filter, C1, C2 As String
Dim counter As Integer
Dim letters() As String
Dim i, x As Integer
Dim char As String

Cells(1, 3).Select
x = 1

'Checks to see if the third column is blank, if not it will continue
While Cells(x, 3).Value <> ""

'Re instantiates an array of size 3 to store the letters (technically 4 since 0 is also a position) Also erases past stored data
ReDim letters(3) As String
i = 0
'Filter stores the whole string
filter = ActiveCell.Value

'Stores the column A and B values  of that row in C1 and C2
C1 = ActiveCell.Offset(, -2).Value
C2 = ActiveCell.Offset(, -1).Value

'This for loop goes through each character of filter string
For counter = 1 To Len(filter)
'char stores the character
char = Mid(filter, counter, 1)
    If char = " " Or char = "&" Then
    Else:
    'stores any character not blank and "&" in an array
    letters(i) = char
    i = i + 1
    End If
Next

'If statement to skip rows that only have 1 letter
If letters(1) <> Empty Then

'For loop that will create a new line and print out array letters in each new row
For i = 0 To 1
ActiveCell.Value = letters(i)
  ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
  ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
  ActiveCell.Offset(, -2).Value = C1
  ActiveCell.Offset(, -1) = C2
  ActiveCell.Value = letters(i + 1)
Next i
End If
x = x + 1
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select

Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks TJYen. This works for letters I will change it as required for me which can have words too in last column.

Comment: for characters you can use a loop to count how many characters until the next blank space. Then just use that in the 'char = Mid(filter, counter, 'number of characters to take in)' to grab the word

Answer (score 0):

As it's a 'one-off' I would do a manual fix

Put all the rows with just one item in column 3 into a new sheet.
Put those with two items in another sheet
And so on
Then, strip out the first item on the two item sheet and copy this into the first sheet
Then strip out the second item on the two item sheet and copy this into the first sheet.
Keep going and eventually you'll have the data as you want it.

Though this takes a long time, it's probably quicker than learning VBA, and writing a routine to do it.

Comment: the data is very large to do this way. Thanks for suggestion though.